# Javascript error : invalid assignment left-hand side

Tags: javascript

Using javascript in Acrobat XI. For some reason, I keep getting the following error:

`invalid assignment left-hand side at 9: line 10`

My code is pretty simple and looks spot on AFAICT. Please review and tell me I'm not crazy. (Or tell me I am, but you have a solution :))

```
function jsNetworkAccount()
{

    // Get a reference to each check box
    var f1 = getField("cbNetworkNotNeeded");
    var f2 = getField("cbNetwork");
    var f3 = getField("cbEmailAccount");

    if (event.target === f1 && event.value = "On") {

           f2.value = "Off";
           f3.value = "Off";
           return;
    }

    if (event.target === f2 || event.target === f3 && event.value = "On") {

           f1.value = "Off"
           return;

    }    
}
```

Comment: boo on the -3. This is a legitimate question about equality in javascript that doesn't seem to make total sense. See answer and comments below.

Comment: It's not a question about equality, it's "please check my JavaScript". It could be a good question if you *at the very least* pointed out which line is line 10 and asked a legit question about why using `=` there isn't allowed.

Comment: @Juhana -> fair point. I didn't learn it was a question about equality until I got the answer. However, had I know it was the `=` sign was throwing it off I would have asked, but I didn't know, so it's hard to ask what you don't know. Also, pointing out line 10 seemed overkill with such short code and only breaking on line 10.

Comment: Reason #26 why VB* is evil:  It's one of the few language families left that uses the same operator for equality and assignment.  If you hadn't gotten used to its brain-damaged syntax, the error would have jumped out at you.

Comment: @cHao -> and wouldn't you know that VB is where I started, so the bad habits are deeply ingrained!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Two equal signs:

```
if (event.target === f1 && event.value =   "On") {
// -------------------------------------^^
if (event.target === f1 && event.value === "On") {


if (event.target === f2 || event.target === f3 && event.value =   "On") {
// ------------------------------------------------------------^^
if (event.target === f2 || event.target === f3 && event.value === "On") {
```

I used three equal signs in my code above for keeping your coding style consistent.

As vol7ron suggested, you should also add parentheses in your IF statements. This greatly improves readability in my opinion.

Comment: this one as well `if (event.target === f2 || event.target = f3 && event.value = "On")`

Comment: and before the `f3`; actually, I think you just mistyped ; edited

Comment: ... or better still, use strict comparison `===`, following the rest of the code.

Comment: @Kyle -> Thanks. I saw the 2nd one and just fixed my post. CornFreek. Thanks for the answer. This is interesting to me, because inside the if statement `f2.value = "On"` to uncheck the combo box. Why do you I need the 3 equal signs in the first if statement?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Using three equal signs forces type checking. Move your code for activating the checkbox into the IF.

Comment: Thanks CornFreek. I guess I just learned some javascript best practice.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman it's also helpful to use parentheses (`()`) when using `&&` and `||` together *or in the presence of complex conditionals*. When bouncing between languages you'll find that some have different precedence rules, whereas parens are generally high up on OoO

Comment: @ScottHoltzman You're welcome. By the way, strict type checking (`===`) also exists in PHP.

Comment: CornFreek, one more question. I should leave my `f2.value = "Off"`, correct? Because I am telling javascript to *assign* the value rather than trying to *compare for equality*

Comment: @ScottHoltzman `f2.value = "Off"` is per se correct, but you shouldn't type it in an IF condition (why do you would need to do so?).