# Invalid left-hand side in assignment Javascript

Tags: javascript

This is my code for opening a popup and doing a HTTP request:
The HTTP request doesn't work yet.
**This is my code:**

```
window.onload = addElement;

function addElement() {
// create a new div element 
// and give it popup content 
var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
var texts;

xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = 
function()
{

    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status = 200)
    {
        texts = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
    else
    {
        texts = 'Waiting for response...';
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "localhost", true);
xmlhttp.send();

newDiv.innerHTML += '<div id="popup" style=" position: fixed;top: 15%;width: 800px;height: 200px;margin: auto;z-index: 99999;display: block;left:25%;background-color: #fff;  border: 1px solid #ddd;  border-radius: 5px;  box-shadow: 0 1px 6px 4px #000;  overflow: hidden;   padding: 10px;"><div class="popup_body" style="  height: 160px;">' + texts + '</div><button style="padding: 10px;" class="close_button"onClick="closePopup()">Sluiten</button><button  style="padding: 10px;" class="close_button"onClick="tostoring()">Meer Informatie</button></div>';

// Add The Background cover
var BG = document.createElement("div");
//BG.style.background-color = 'black';
BG.style.width = '100%';
BG.style.height = '100%';
BG.style.background = 'black';
BG.style.position = 'fixed';
BG.style.top = '0';
BG.style.left = '0';
BG.style.opacity = '0.7';
BG.style.zIndex = '99900';
BG.style.display = 'none';
BG.setAttribute("id", "bgcover");

// add the newly created elements and its content into the DOM 
document.body.appendChild(BG);
document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, BG);
// open popup onload

openPopup();
}

function openPopup() {
  var el = document.getElementById('popup');
  var BG = document.getElementById('bgcover');
  el.style.display = 'block';
  BG.style.display = 'block';
}

function tostoring() {
     window.location.href='http://localhost/Sms%20management%20systeem/testing/storing.php';
 }

function closePopup() {
  var el = document.getElementById('popup');
  var BG = document.getElementById('bgcover');
  el.style.display = 'none';
  BG.style.display = 'none';
}
```

What does this error mean?
How can I fix this error?
I'm stuck because my code doesn't work when I have this error.
I know it could be the if statement but I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: What line results in the left side error?

Comment: if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status = 200)
    {
        texts = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
    else
    {
        texts = 'Waiting for response...';
    }

Comment: `if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status = 200)` souhld be `if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)`

Comment: `xmlhttp.status = 200` should be `xmlhttp.status == 200` or better yet `xmlhttp.status === 200`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript error : invalid assignment left-hand side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19015213/javascript-error-invalid-assignment-left-hand-side)

Comment: nope, my code is different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xmlhttp.status = 200` should be `xmlhttp.status === 200`
I made an mistake with the compare of the two values.
Thanks @Francois wahl.

Answer (score -1):

This error is caused by operator precedence:

`&&` has higher precedence than `=` so:

> ```
> (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status = 200)
> ```

is treated as:

```
( (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status) = 200)
```

The left hand side isn't a variable or a property, so you can't assign to it.

You don't really want to assign to it though. You are trying to **compare** and you made a typo.

`xmlhttp.status = 200` should be `xmlhttp.status == 200`

Comment: `status` property can be overwritten. The issue is that an assignment is used where there was none expected.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl — If it could be overwritten, it wouldn't throw an exception when the OP tried to write to it.

Comment: Of course the `status` property can be overwritten. The issue has nothing to do with the `status` property but that **any** assignment was attempted where there was none expected. Huge difference.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl — What makes an assignment unexpected *there* other than the fact it is the status property of an XHR instance?

Comment: `The status property does not allow you to write to it.` is an incorrect interpretation of the error. The property is not `readonly` and can be changed at any time. It's important to differentiate if a property is `readonly` and can't be modified or if you tried to assign a value where no assignment was expected.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl — What makes an assignment unexpected there? If the property can be changed "at any time", why can't it be changed there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130939/discussion-between-francois-wahl-and-quentin).

Comment: I don't really want to continue going around in circles, so I'm not going to take this to chat. I eventually figured out the reason.

Comment: Taking it to chat is an automatic comment by SO,..not sure why they add my name to it instead of SO names :)