# Reformatting Strings - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I've been given a task that has to reformat incorrect phone numbers (that are strings) in javascript. The correct output has to be: 123-456-789 or 123-456-789-11 (depending on how many characters there are in the string)?

I have a basic java background and am still getting used to the way javascript works...

Example cases:

```
00-44 48 5555 8361
0 - 22 1985--324
555372654
```

Example cases should ne:

```
004-448-555-583-61
022-198-53-24
555-372-654
```

The code will eventually ignore the dashes and spaces so that correct output can be generated

This is what i have so far:

```
S = S.replace("", "");

for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    var after = S.replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, '$1-');
    console.log(after);
}
```

Cheers

Comment: If `n` is the length (an integer), it won't have the `.replace` method. Did you mean `S.replace(…)`?

Comment: Please add the example value(s) for `S` and the expected output for that particular example.

Comment: I didn't see that, thanks... But apparently the errors is coming from the if statement: ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment)

Comment: test cases has been added

Comment: Oh, [that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19015213/1048572) as well. You should always include the error message in your question if you are getting one.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Is my solution correct for what ii'm aiming to do?

Comment: Does it work for your test cases or not? It's your choice to judge it as correct.

Comment: That's fair. I've change the code after a little researching, it removes the spaces and dashes. But i'm not sure how to dashes in...

Comment: @GeorgeGilliland Check my answer below or some of the others. You have complete solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `S=["00-44 48 5555 8361","0 - 22 1985--324","555372654"]`

**All you need is one line:**

```
S.map(str=>str.replace(/[- ]/g, "").match(/(\d{1,3})/g).join('-'));
```

Which will iterate your array of strings, remove all spaces and -, then match 1 to 3 digits (greedy first, so 3 whenever possible) and ultimately join these matches with `-` between.

Run example below:

```js
console.log(
            ["00-44 48 5555 8361","0 - 22 1985--324","555372654"]
                .map(str=>str.replace(/[- ]/g, '')
                         .match(/(\d{1,3})/g)
                         .join('-')
                    )
           );
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it, is to first remove all the numbers then split on every third number. Followed by joining the array with a `-`

```js
const tests = [
  '123-15 68--5722',
  '123-15 68     52',
  '123--125--68--572',
  '123 a b c 15 68 d efg   52',
]

function format(num) {
  // Remove everything that isn't a number
  return num.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')
    // Spilt on every 3rd number
    .match(/\d{1,3}/g)
    // Join with dashes
    .join('-')
}

tests.forEach(num => console.log(format(num)))
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You used assignment operator(=) instead of equality operator(==) in the if block.
2. As your code indicate 'n' is the length of the string. So n.replace() will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to match groups of three digits.

```js
var inputs = ['00-44 48 5555 8361', '0 - 22 1985--324', '555372654', 
              '123456798', '12345678911', '', '1'];

inputs.forEach(function(input) {
    var strippedInput = input.replace(/[\s-]/g, '');
    var formattedInput = strippedInput.replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, '$1-');
    console.log(formattedInput);
});
```

What the regex does is:

- It looks for groups of exactly three digits `(\d{3})`
- ...*immediately followed by* at least another digit `(?=\d)`
- and replaces it with the matched group and a dash `$1-`

That strangely looking `(?=\d)` is a positive lookahead to not include the fourth digit after. This prevents adding a superfluous dash at the end of your formatted string.

Note that you can replace dashes and spaces in one single step using a character group `[\s-]`.

Output:

```
004-448-555-583-61
022-198-532-4
555-372-654
123-456-798
123-456-789-11

1
```

Answer (score 0):

Some general tips to solve this:

1) You might want to remove whitespaces and dashes from the input first, e.g.:

```
S = S.replace(" ", "")
```

2) You can access a certain character in a string by index like this:

```
S[i] // e.g. "0"
```

3) To check if you are at the third position were a dash needs to be added, just use modulo on the position:

```
if(n % 3 === 0) { /* add - */}
```

4) You can build up a new string and add characters with `+=`:

```
let result = "123";
result += "-";
```